# Changed lines on deleted Item in Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

### Description

Assuming that I'm getting the changed lines count from the `Chromium` reporsitori'es specific file., like this :

`svn diff "G:\Develop\Google\Chromium\trunk\src\webkit\glue\entity_map.h" -c 3116`

### Problem

The problem is that `entity_map.h` doesn't more exist, cause it was *probabbly* removed. 
So it doesn't exist not in Working Copy, not in Repository.

So my query fails, cause there is nothing to compare with each other. Even if I try to restore the file by using techniques I found on internet, like

- `svn up` (not recommended)
- `svn copy`

It fails by the way cause there is no Counterpart to compare with and determine the difference made on file. 
But good news are that `TortoiseSVN` suceeds in this, so I'm pretty sure *there is a way* of doing that.

### Question

Does anyone know how to get changed lines count on the file *in specific revision* considering that file was removed long times ago. ?

**EDIT**

Would prefer avoid to use `Subverison` specific `C` functions, but use just `command-line` interface provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use `svn diff` with `-r oldrev:newrev` - where you are comparing against the 2 specified revision #'s, and where both revision #'s exist.

Assuming maybe the file was instead moved, so that it just no longer exists at the same location, and you still wish to compare, this syntax may also prove helpful:

> diff OLD-URL[@OLDREV] NEW-URL[@NEWREV]

Most of the svn commands, including `svn diff` are quite full-featured.  Please check `svn help diff` to see all of the available options - with explanations for each.

Comment: *If* it was moved, and *if* I know its location, may be. But what if it was **removed** ? So no longer present in repository. Reverting everything till that revision seems a madness to me, only for benefit of having changed lines information.

Comment: You can't **remove** things from the repository (short of doing a dump/load and essentially creating a new repository).  It may have been removed from "trunk", but will still exist at a previous version # - if it ever existed.  You can still compare against such artifacts by using the syntax examples noted above, even if they no longer exist in the current revision.